# Covert ERC-20 tokens with different decimals to amount to Wei

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, web3js

For example when I want to send `ERC-20` tokens to a contract, I specify the amount in Wei
So I have to convert `34678393` tokens to Wei. But it only works ok with tokens that have 18 decimals

I'm using web3's `toWei()` function like so

```
  const sendTokens = async (amount)  => {
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract("ADDRESS",ABI)
    await contract.sendTokens(web3.utils.toWei(amount))
  }
```

How can I convert tokens amount with different decimals to Wei?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this function to convert the amount to WEI based on Token Decimal.

```
function tokenAmountToWei(amount, decimals) {
    return web3.utils.toBN("0x" + (amount * 10 ** decimals).toString(16)).toString();
}

let erc20_decimals = 6;
let amount = 5000;

console.log(tokenAmountToWei(amount, erc20_decimals))
```

Comment: is there a Python equivalent for this? what does `.toString(16)` do? I don't see that the function accepts a parameter

Comment: @ekkis You can convert this script to Python.
`.toString(16)` convert the base of the number to HEX.
Any commands that do the same (converts a number to a hexidecima) can solve your problem.